# Ubuntu 20.04 (Unity), wifi disconnects when the system is idle (screensaver)

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04, unity

Ubuntu 20.04 (Unity), wifi disconnects when the system is idle (screensaver).

How I can prevent such behavior?

Comment: Go to Settings -> Power -> turn off "Wi-Fi can be turned off to save power"

Comment: I didn't have such an option in Power at Unity.